# Prove that the no. of selections of n things from two sets of n identical things and n other distinct things is (n+2)×2^(n-1)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs, analytic-combinatorics

Prove that the number of selections of $n$ things from two sets of $n$ identical things and $n$ other distinct things is $(n+2)\cdot 2^{(n-1)}$.

I have been trying to come up with a combinatorial proof but havent made any headway. Can anyone help me out with the proof?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we will partition the problem in two subproblems.

The first is the selection of k things out of the distinguishible set. If we select k things out of an n-set we have $ \binom{n}{k} $ possibilities.

The second one is the selection of $ n-k $ items of lets say red and green balls. first we can select 0 red and  n-k green, then 1 red and n-k-1 green and so on, leaving us with n-k+1 possibilies.

Putting the two together we get $ \binom{n}{k} (n-k+1) $ possibilities where you choose k things out of the distinguishible set. Summing over $ k = 1,2,...,n $ and using the binomial formula, we get: $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (n-k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (n-k) + \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} (n-k) + 2^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k-1)!} + 2^n = n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} + 2^n = n2^{n-1} + 2^n = (n+2)2^{n-1}$$

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Cheers!!